# longtable from csv how to bold specific rows?

Tags: longtable, bold, csv

I am creating long table from csv file. I want specific rows to be in bold font.  how to do it ?  Csv file is huge.
I have tried \textbf{} as it works in normal table from csv file.
My code is ..

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
\toprule
\midrule \endhead
\bottomrule 
\caption{Feature Description}
\label{summary_tbl_14}
\endfoot
    \csvreader[
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6}]{csv/Summary.csv}
    {1=\AttrName, 2=\Vt, 3=\Vf,4=\Vs,5=\Ve,6=\Vn,7=\Vt,8=\Vel,9=\Vte}    
    {\AttrName & \Vt & \Vf & \Vs & \Ve & \Vn & \Vt & \Vel & \Vte}
\end{longtable}
```

Sample rows from CSV ..

AttrName,Vt,Vf,Vs,Ve,Vn,Vt,Vel,Vte

Min.,29,0,-18,-9,1,1,0,-9

1stQu.,48,0,-9,-9,3,120,0,212

Comment: code is not appearing in proper format here .. please help

Comment: Use `{}` Button to mark code...

Comment: The code would look fine if it was compilable (see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) You can use filecontents package to include a part of the csv too and fix it.